# Can I update text in tkinter graphics?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a pong game, but I have some problems with my score counter. I want it to bounce around the screen and bump into the ball. however, because I have it draw only once in the init function, when the score changes, the counter does not change. I am trying to find a way to update the score counter without changing location. Second, the text does not interact with the ball. The both the text and the ball bounce off the paddle, but the ball doesn’t bounce off the text. You can see my code here.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
import os

score = 0
print ('Score: ' + str(score))
class Ball:
  def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, text, color):
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.paddle = paddle
    self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
    self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
    starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
    random.shuffle(starts)
    self.x = starts[0]
    self.y = -3
    self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
    self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
    self.hit_bottom = False

  def hit_paddle(self, pos):
    global score
    paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
    if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
      if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
        score = score + 1
    
        os.system('clear')
        print ('Score: ' + str(score))
        return True
    return False

  def hit_text(self, pos):
    text_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.text.id)
    if pos[2] >= text_pos[0] and pos[0] <= text_pos[2]:
      if pos[3] >= text_pos[1] and pos[3] <= text_pos[3]:
        return True
    return False
  
  def draw(self):
    self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
    if pos[1] <= 0:
      self.y = 1
    if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
      self.hit_bottom = True
    #if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
      #self.y = -1
    if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
      self.y = -3
    if pos[0] <= 0:
      self.x = 3
    if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
      self.x = -3
      
class Paddle:
  def __init__(self, canvas, color):
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
    self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
    self.x = 0
    self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
    self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
    self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
    self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', self.turn_stop)

  def draw(self):
    self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
    if pos[0] <= 0:
      self.x = 0
    elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
      self.x = 0
      
  def turn_left(self, evt):
    self.x = -2
  def turn_right(self, evt):
    self.x = 2
  def turn_stop(self, evt):
    self.x = 0

class Text:
  def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
    global score
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.paddle = paddle
    
    self.id = canvas.create_text(10, 20, text="Score: " + str(score), fill=color, font=("Arial", 15))
    self.canvas.move(self, 245, 100)
    starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
    random.shuffle(starts)
    self.x = starts[0]
    self.y = -3
    self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
    self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()

  

  def hit_paddle(self, pos):
    paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
    if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
      if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
        return True
    return False

  def draw(self):
    global score
    self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
    pos = canvas.bbox(self.id)
    if pos[1] <= 0:
      self.y = 1
    if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
      self.y = -1
    if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
      score = score + 1
      self.y = -3
      self.x = -3
    if pos[0] <= 0:
      self.x = 3
    if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
      self.x = -3


tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
text = Text(canvas, paddle, 'black')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, text, 'red')

while 1:
  if ball.hit_bottom == False:
    ball.draw()
    paddle.draw()
    text.draw()
  tk.update_idletasks()
  tk.update()
  time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Ball class. I removed

- hit_paddle function, so you don't need it.

In Text class in draw function:

- I  removed in line 116 `score = score + 1`
- Added at the end of draw function.

  self.canvas.itemconfig(self.id,
  text=f'Score: {str(score)}')

Here is code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
import os

score = 0

class Ball:
  def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, text, color):
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.paddle = paddle
    self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
    self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
    starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
    random.shuffle(starts)
    self.x = starts[0]
    self.y = -3
    self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
    self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
    self.hit_bottom = False

  def hit_paddle(self, pos):
    global score
    paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
    if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
      if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
        self.y = -3  
        score = score + 1   
        print ('Score: ' + str(score))
        return True
    return False
  
  def draw(self):
    self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
    if pos[1] <= 0:
      self.y = 1
    if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
      self.hit_bottom = True
    #if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
      #self.y = -1
    if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
      self.y = -3
    if pos[0] <= 0:
      self.x = 3
    if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
      self.x = -3
      
class Paddle:
  def __init__(self, canvas, color):
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
    self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
    self.x = 0
    self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
    self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
    self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
    self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', self.turn_stop)

  def draw(self):
    self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
    if pos[0] <= 0:
      self.x = 0
    elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
      self.x = 0
      
  def turn_left(self, evt):
    self.x = -2
    
  def turn_right(self, evt):
    self.x = 2
    
  def turn_stop(self, evt):
    self.x = 0

class Text:
  def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
    global score
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.paddle = paddle
    
    self.id = canvas.create_text(10, 20, text="Score: " + str(score), fill=color, font=("Arial", 15))
    self.canvas.move(self, 245, 100)
    starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
    random.shuffle(starts)
    self.x = starts[0]
    self.y = -3
    self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
    self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
   
  def hit_paddle(self, pos):
    global score  
    paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
    if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
      if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
        return True
    return False

  def draw(self):
    global score
    self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
    pos = canvas.bbox(self.id)
    if pos[1] <= 0:
      self.y = 1
    if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
      self.y = -1
    if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:              
      self.y = -3
      self.x = -3      
    if pos[0] <= 0:
      self.x = 3
    if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
      self.x = -3
    self.canvas.itemconfig(self.id, text=f'Score: {str(score)}')

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
text = Text(canvas, paddle, 'black')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, text, 'red')

while 1:
  if ball.hit_bottom == False:
    ball.draw()
    paddle.draw()
    text.draw()
  tk.update_idletasks()
  tk.update()
  time.sleep(0.01)
```

Result:

[image]